# Overriding == equality operator works only in one direction

Tags: ruby, oop, operator-overloading, overriding, equality

Consider next example where I override `==` operator to return `true` constantly:

```
class Example
  def ==(other)
    return true
  end
end
```

However, this only works in one direction:

```
exp = Example.new
puts exp == {} #=> true
puts {} == exp #=> false
```

Is there a way to force this equality method to work in the reverse direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible without changing other classes. Basically `a == b` equals `a.==(b)`. So you need to override `==` operator for the second class if you want to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to force this equality method to also work in the reverse direction?

No, but you can change `Hash#==` to recognize the special case of `Example`.

```
class Example
  def ==(other)
    return true
  end
end

class Hash
  alias_method :original_double_equals, :==

  def ==(other)
    case other
    when Example
      other == self
    else
      original_double_equals(other)
    end
  end
end


exp = Example.new
exp == {} # => true
{} == exp # => true
{} == {} # => true
{foo: 1} == {foo: 2} # => false
```

I wouldn't do this, if I were you.

Comment: You could also, alias the `==` method before you redefine it: `alias :original_double_equals :"=="` between lines 7 and 8 in your example and then instead of `super` call `original_double_equals(other)`...yields `true`, `true`, `true`, `false` as the outputs

Comment: @SimpleLime: actually, this does sound like a better idea. Lemme do that

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.

Ruby is an object-oriented language. The *fundamental idea* of OO is that you send messages to objects and the receiver object, and *nothing but the receiver* object gets to decide how to respond to that message.

- If you send the message `==` to object `a`, passing object `b` as an argument, then `a` *and `a` alone* gets to decide how to respond.
- If you send the message `==` to object `b`, passing object `a` as an argument, then `b` *and `b` alone* gets to decide how to respond.

The *only way* that this is guaranteed to give the same response, is if `a` and `b` cooperate and *agree* to give the same response.

It would theoretically be possible to design a language in such a way that `a == b` is not a message send to either `a` or `b`, but rather a message send to some *third* "context object". IOW, `a == b` is not interpreted as `a.==(b)` or `b.==(a)` but rather `some_context_object.==(a, b)` (for example, the context object could just be yourself, i.e. `self.==(a, b)`). In that case, the context object has access to the *public* API of both `a` and `b` and could take steps to ensure that `==` is commutative.

But in general, and by the fundamental nature of OO, messages are non-commutative, and the receiver object is special.